# Property of object inside indexedDB showing a value, when retrieved showing another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

In chrome "Application" -> IndexedDB I see the property value of an object with value "inactive",
on retrieving that record, the property shows with value "active".

This is the function that does the retrieving:

```js
function retrievesClientsFrom(databaseWithThisName, thisVersion, thisObjectStoreName) {
  var requestToOpenDatabase = indexedDB.open(databaseWithThisName, thisVersion);

  requestToOpenDatabase.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var theDatabaseObject = requestToOpenDatabase.result;

    //gets a transaction object
    var theTransactionObject = theDatabaseObject.transaction(thisObjectStoreName, "readonly");

    //gets the object store with that name
    var theObjectStore = theTransactionObject.objectStore(thisObjectStoreName);

    //gets all objects inside the objectStore sent to the function
    var requestToGetContentOfAnObjectStore = theObjectStore.getAll();
    requestToGetContentOfAnObjectStore.onsuccess = function(event) {
      arrayOfRetrievedClients = requestToGetContentOfAnObjectStore.result;
      //here I get the wrong value (I see it in chrome console).
      console.log("arrayOfRetrievedClients: o%",arrayOfRetrievedClients); 
    };
  };

  requestToOpenDatabase.onerror = function(event) {
    window.alert("There was a problem reading the database: 
      "+requestToOpenDatabase.error);
  };
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on when you call `retrievesClientsFrom`. I bet you are writing, not waiting for the write to complete, reading, and then checking devtools. You need to wait to read until the write completes. But you are not showing all the other code, so it is hard to help you.

Comment: @Josh, thank you for your answer. I am calling it from different places in the app, I thought it was too much code to put over here. I thought I have followed every step in the order they happen, but I guess I am doing as you say, forgetting that the communication with the database is not synchronous. I will try to look at that.

Comment: @Josh, I did as you suggested, putting the function that reads the database inside the IDBTransaction.oncomplete = function(event){//calling the retrieving function}, but the error persisted, and I finally found the silliest of mistakes, inside two (!) different 'if' clauses, I was assigning instead of comparing! I guess too sleepy at the moment. ( if(sth = sthElse) instead of if(sth === sthElse). Of course the clarification is not for you, but for any other beginner that arrives here with a similar problem. Thank you again!